# GAE: NDB query on list

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Google App Engine NDB data model like so:

```
Users
    Username
    FirstName
    LastName

Posts
    PostID
    PosterUsername

SubscribedPosts
    PostID
    SubscriberUsername
```

For a specific user, I want to return all the Posts which the user is subscribed to and display them on the page.

Since the wonderful NDB doesn't support JOINs, we do two queries:

```
postIDList = 
SubscribedPosts.query(SubscribedPosts.SubscriberUsername == 'johndoe').fetch()
```

This gives us a list of SubscribedPosts.  So how do I take my postIDList list and use it as a filter criteria for a Posts query?

Something like:

```
results = Posts.query(Post.PostID IN postIDList.PostID)
```

In a normal relational database, this would be a simple query using table joins.  How is this done in Google's ndb?

Comment: Do I have to add a repeated column (ie: a list) to Posts which would be a list of Usernames who had subscribed to that post?  Rather than the normalized relational design of having the SubscribedPosts for many-to-many relations?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to run into lots of bottlenecks if you try to design your datastore models the same way you would design tables in a relational database as you have in this example.

Your comment goes in one possible right direction, although there are other solutions.  Going that route, I would drop the "subscribedPosts" model altogether use a repeated KeyProperty entity in the User model to store subscribed posts.

See this related post: [One-To-Many Example in NDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077300/one-to-many-example-in-ndb)

Comment: Also should probably use the parent/ancestor model behavior rather than psuedo joins.

Comment: Wouldn't querying a IN relationship for a repeated property degrade as the repeated property grows any larger than, say 10 properties?

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are looking to model a many-to-many relationship, not one-to-many.  Read [Modelling Entity Relationships](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling) (althought this is for the older `db`, not newer `ndb`, it still gives the idea).

One of the two entities should maintain a list of keys (repeated=True) of the related other entities.  Which entity should hold the list?  Preferably the list should be on the side that usually has fewer relationships so that the list of keys is smaller.  Another consideration is which side likely has less contention for updates.

In your specific case, lets say on average users subscribe to 10 posts and lets say on average each post has 100 users subscribed to it.  In this case, we would want to put the list of keys on `Users` side of the relation.

```
class Users(ndb.Model):
    user_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    first_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    last_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    posts = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Posts', repeated=True)

class Posts(ndb.Model)
    post_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    poster_user_name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Establish the relationship by adding to the list in the `Users` instance:

```
current_user.posts.append(current_post.key)
```

For a given `Users` instance, getting all subscribed `Posts` is easy since the list of keys of the subscribed `Posts` is already within the given `Users`:

```
ndb.get_multi(given_user.posts)
```

For a given `Posts` instance, get all subscribing `Users` by ...

```
query = Users.query(Users.posts == given_post.key)
```

Comment: I was just so rooted in the relational DB mindset that I designed a relational schema rather than whatever paradigm NDB follows.

Comment: One problem with repeated properties is they are limited in size.  If you have a reasonably small set of possible items then they are practical. But if it can be a fairly large set then you will need an intermediate entity which is effectively represents a pre=computed join.